# How ro create Jasmine fixture without jquery

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I try implement `Javascripts` tests for `html` using `Jasmine` fixture by [this](http://searls.testdouble.com/posts/2011-12-11-jasmine-fixtures.html) tutorial. And get this error:

```
$container = $('<gesurvey></gesurvey>').appendTo('body');
         ^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I guess this is for `jquery` but I want implement it using vanilla `JavaScript`.

If I try use:

```
var elemDiv = document.createElement('gesurvey');
document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
```

I got:

```
var elemDiv = document.createElement('gesurvey');
                       ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Comment: are you running this on a html or is this commandline? Because its a specRunner.html where your spec is, it should work just fine

Comment: no I use `jasmine` command in terminal

Comment: I don't think if commandline js supports DOM elements. Node.js does support command line but not with DOM I guess. May I know your limitations with using specRunner like plain html way of using jasmine?

Comment: You give me good direction. Now I use specRunner.html file for do tests, and now I can play with DOM.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please post your answer and mark it answered so that this thread can have a closure.